# Using delimiter in Python to cut out middle section

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, delimiter

I have a text file that is comma-separated with five different columns but I only want to get back the first column and the fourth column.

When I am using the `split` function it is just splitting everything and I don't know how to get it so that it will just take the first column and then skip to the fourth column.

This is an example of the data I am trying to organise:

```
11.332,2,2,-465,0.928621379033569
```

What I would like to get back from this is `11.332` and `-465` and forget about the rest of it

Comment: *"When i am using the split function it is just splitting everything"* - well that's what it's supposed to do. *"i don't know how to get it so that it will just take the first column and then skip to the fourth column"* - why not do that afterwards? `for row in data: first, fourth = row[0], row[3]`. If using 3.x, you could use some clever unpacking tricks, see e.g. https://repl.it/Bte9

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do it.

Your question is tagged with `csv`. You can parse CSV data with the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) module:

```
import csv

with open('file.csv') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        print(row[0])    # the first field
        print(row[3])    # the third field
```

For your sample data this would print:

```
11.332
-465
```

`csv.reader()` is probably the best way to go, however, another method is to use tuple unpacking with `_` to denote ignored fields:

```
line = '11.332,2,2,-465,0.928621379033569'
first, _, _, fourth, _ = line.split(',')
print(first)
print(fourth)
# 11.332
# -465
```

Of course there is nothing stopping you from binding all of the fields to variables, just replace `_` with a meaningful variable name.

Alternatively you can split the whole line and then pluck out the fields that you want by subscripting:

```
line = '11.332,2,2,-465,0.928621379033569'
data = '11.332,2,2,-465,0.928621379033569'.split(',')
print(data[0])
print(data[3])
# 11.332
# -465
```

Or you could use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) (combined with tuple unpacking):

```
from operator import itemgetter

fields = itemgetter(0, 3)
first, fourth = fields(line.split(','))
print first
print fourth
# 11.332
# -465
```

Comment: thanks for this @mhawke , loads of different options here. These are working for printing them out but once i try and read the values into a variable instead of printing them i keep getting a list index out of range error

Comment: @Darby_321: How are you assigning them? Each of the examples above shows the values being assigned to variables before printing. How is your code or situation different?

Comment: @Darby_321: You should update your question with the code that you are using.

Comment: sorry i realized now my problem was in the file i was reading in and not in the code. in the file one line had BEGIN_SESSION and no comma separated values which was throwing up the error. i knew it couldn't have been that hard to get working

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out

```
for line in eda:
    print (line.split(',')[0])
    print (line.split(',')[3])
```

This is giving me out the two results that i need and forgetting about the rest of them

Comment: You're doing the same work twice - `split` once, *then* index.

Comment: @jonsharpe what way do i do that because i am actually after running into trouble with it again because i am trying to read them into a variable instead of printing them but for the second line split it is is giving me a list index out of range??

Comment: ... `stuff = line.split(','); print(stuff[0], stuff[3])`?